# Converting old Html SIZE=+x to css

Tags: html, css, deprecated

I'm remaking an old website with html and CSS, having never made a website with "old-style" mark-up I have no idea what the size=+x relates to in CSS, is it pixels or what? Is there a way of replicating this in css or do i have to specify the size exactly?

In short, how do i add x pixels to something i dont know the size of?

For my particular example here is the mark-up:

```
<H1 ALIGN=CENTER>
    <B><FONT color="red" SIZE=+4>PHONE BOOK</FONT></B>
</H1></CENTER>
```

Comment: It's even made complete with a stray closing `</CENTER>` tag!

Comment: you should see some of the stuff they did with frames and tables >.<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This dirty old value is equivalent to this css

```
.item{
  font-size: xxx-large;
}
```

That's if you view it in webkit.
In firefox, it's about 48px.

[Here's the old plus and minus tags in action](http://www.ftls.org/en/tutorial/HTML/index4.shtml)

[Here's the W3C's details of the modern equivalents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props)

The old font sizes are set relative to the browsers current default font-size.
It's not the sort of thing you want to leave up to chance, if you want your site to look how it was designed.

Want my opinion, dump it, and use a value of em or px instead.

For the good of your sanity, don't sweat too much over matching these crummy old values, do it by sight, or if you're really worried, do pixel comparisons of screen-grabs.

Comment: so the +4 is a defined size? not adding 4 pixels or something?

Comment: It's 4 "steps" up form the browser default. But the steps aren't even, in a modern browser, they sort of ramp up and then level off. Pure muck. I've added a link you can use to evaluate in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

in short the  tag has 7 sizes for text: 1-7.
the default was always 3 when used size=+1 it means make it a size larger than 3 (same as size=4).

it was used so different web browsers will show the page correctlly (their sizes are apparentlly different size 3 on explorer wasnt the same on firefox etc)

in css just define a font and a decent letter size and be done with it.

for further reading: http://www.jonstorm.com/html/font.htm

Answer (score 0):

Much of this depends on the base font size used on the page, as well as how those font sizes are defined in the stylesheet. The best way to determine the actual size use to use Firebug. Inspect the element and open the "Computed" tab of the right. It will tell you the font size in pixels.

Comment: so there is no means of "incrementing" a font size in css?

Comment: There is... with `larger` and `smaller`, but that's about it. I don't know how close it is to the font size attribute.

Comment: if i use `h1{font-size:larger;}` it makes the text smaller

Comment: Jacxel - if you want relative font sizes, look at using "em"s as your units. See: http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: @Jacxel `{font-size:larger}` _does_ make the size larger. However, things like `h1` are special: h1 has `{font-size:200%}` by default, so if you override that in your own stylesheet with `{font-size:larger}` it makes the font only a bit larger than normal text, not twice the size as it would have been.

Comment: @Jacxel Note that if you apply `{font-size:larger}` to an element _inside_ the H1 (in your original example, the `<b>`) then that element would get a larger text than the h1.